# Why alpha animation doesn't work when alpha is already set at view

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

I found a weird situation. The `animation.xml` of the below doesn't work. `ImageView` is always invisible.

*activity.xml*

```
...
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="324px"
      android:layout_height="90px"
      android:alpha="0"
      android:src="@drawable/img"
      android:id="@+id/img"/>
...
```

*custom_anim.xml* (invisible to visible)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.custom_anim);
...
...
((ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.img)).startAnimation(anim);
```

However, if remove the line `android:alpha` on the `activity.xml`, animation work. Of course the `ImageView` is not invisible before the animation work but at least it can be worked. Please let me know why it is happened and how can i make the animation can be worked with the line `android:alpha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using below code

```
((ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.img)).animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).start();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked! Thank you! 
If you get the reason of why xml can't control alpha value, give me comments please!